# Change Default Route to HTTPS - Zend 1.10

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

Is there a way to do as mentioned in the title? Currently, all URL request goes to http://www.url.com regardless if we enter https://www.url.com

My code is Bootstrap.php is:

```
    class Core_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
    {   


  protected function _initDoctype()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('view');
        $view = $this->getResource('view');

        $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/core/views/helpers','Core_View_Helper');
        //$view->controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();

        $view->doctype('XHTML1_TRANSITIONAL');

        // setting content type and character set
        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8')
            ->appendHttpEquiv('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=7')
            ->appendHttpEquiv('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=EmulateIE7');

        $frontend= array(
            'lifetime' => 7200,
            'automatic_serialization' => true
        );

        $backend= array(
            'cache_dir' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../data/cache',
        );

        $cache = Zend_Cache::factory(
            'core',
            'File',
            $frontend,
            $backend
        );

        Zend_Registry::set('cache',$cache);
    }

    protected function _initRoutes()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
        $front = $this->getResource('FrontController');
        $router = $front->getRouter();

        $route['page'] = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
            '([^\.]+)\.html',
            array(
                'module'    => 'cms',
                'controller' => 'page',
                'action'     => 'view'
            )
        );

        $router->addRoute('page', $route['page']);
    }
}
```

htaccess for redirection is useless as it creates a indirect loop. It seems like all url with https will be redirected to http. Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Please note that there should be only one htaccess at the root of the application.
Check your public folder and remove .htaccess if it is there